# iPhone - How to send apprequests using facebook iOS sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, request

i'm working on an iphone app, in which i need to send application request(invitation and app gift) to the users.

In API all the methods and examples are given for FB web apps,i tried to mimic them but they all return null in response.Can some please guide me how to do that using FB iOS sdk.

### EDIT

okey, i triend to post using this URL and its sending request to me but not to other users and returning this error : "(#200) All users in param ids must have accepted TOS"

```
NSString *st = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/apprequests?message='TestMessage'&access_token=%@&method=post",accesToken];
```

So this request increase a count at application bookmark, when would notification triggered ?

Still confused, like okey we can not send request to users who aren't using application, how can we encourage them to use application.

what if i want to send him a gift, and he is not using the application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey check this post out: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7751806/facebook-requests-dialog-frictionless-requests-in-native-ios-app-possible

You can now do a requests dialog by using the dialog "apprequests".

Answer (score 2):

The Requests dialog is not currently supported with the iOS SDK as documented in the README documentation

hope this helps

Comment: yeah, i read that. The only way to send application request is using Request Dialog, so does that means iOS apps can not send app request?Thanksl

Comment: That is correct, but I heard facebook is working on that so you can just wait.

Comment: In Zynga application like farmVille or cityVille on iPhone, user can send request without popping a request dialog. Correct me if i'm wrong. what would they be doing ..

Comment: You have to have authorized the app before you can be sent invitations, so likely, the users have Farmville installed already.