# Facebook , OSX and FB Requests

Tags: facebook, macos, fbrequest-form

We are in the process of converting one of our games from iOS over to the OSX app market. A big part of our game is the social features which we use the iOS sdk for our game.  We are starting to run into a problem where we cannot find any details on whether fb requests can be done via OSX. We have the auth process down and access to the graph API.

So just to be clear, we are looking to:

Pull a list of friends (which is easy via graph api)
Select a friend
Then send that friend an app request (which we cant seem to find any details on how to do this on osx)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

See the "Direct URL Example" in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

It also appears to be covered in the "Requests" section of the [Facebook iOS tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/)

THis has also been asked before: [iPhone - How to send apprequests using facebook iOS sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274950/iphone-how-to-send-apprequests-using-facebook-ios-sdk)

Comment: note this is not iOS its OSX compete different beast, unless your saying the iOS calls can be used on OSX Desktop app?

Comment: The underlying Facebook calls are the same though so the Direct URL Example is what you're after, whether it's wrapped in a platform specific framework or not.

Comment: Matt thanks, im still having issues with some of these calls on OSX app, has any one actually tried and got these all running on a osx desktop app?